# Bound Mismatch on new object of generic class

Tags: java, generics

I have an error occuring with a program for an assignment. In it, I have to create an own generic

```
public class LinkedList<E extends Comparable<T>> implements List<E> {
```

the implemented Interface is:

```
public interface List<E extends Comparable<T>> { }
```

Now, whenever I try to create a new object of the type LinkedList as follows:

```
LinkedList<Termin> k = new LinkedList<Termin>();
```

eclipse gives me the following error:

> - Bound mismatch: The type Termin is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter > of the type
>     LinkedList

the class declaration of the class Termin is as follows:

```
public class Termin implements Comparable<T> { }
```

in case you need the constructor and variables of the LinkedList object:

```
    private E item;
    private LinkedList<E> next;

//Constructor
    public LinkedList() {
        item = null;
        next = null;
    }
```

With a little google magic, I also found out that there once was a bug involving generics in eclipse that gave the same error for no reason.

I suppose some of my declarations aren't entirely correct.

Comment: If `E` is the type of the list elements, what is `T`?

Comment: Bound mismatch: is that only compilation error you are getting?

Comment: T is the type of comparable itself.

And yes, the bound mismatch is the only error I am receiving.

Comment: @user1016675: you almost certainly want `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way the code is written, it cannot compile for a number of reasons, including the lack of specification of the `T` type, which is not explicitly declared.

One solution is to remove `T` and replace it with a known `Java` type (e.g., `Object`).

A more generic solution is to include `T`, which means two generic types have to be used.

For the latter case, the code could be something like:

```
// LinkedList class
public class LinkedList<T, E extends Comparable<T>> implements List<T, E> {
    private E item;
    private LinkedList<T, E> next;

    // Constructor
    public LinkedList() {
        item = null;
        next = null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Example statement, where T = Long.class and E = String.class
        LinkedList<Long, Termin<String>> k = new LinkedList<Long, Termin<String>>();
    }
}
```

and

```
// List interface    
public interface List<T, E extends Comparable<T>> { }
```

and

```
// Termin class
public class Termin<T> implements Comparable<T> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(T o) {
        return 0; // Actual comparison needs to be implemented
    }
}
```